# Google Cloud Datastore, simultaneous read/write, conflicts possible?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

Scenario is, I start a lot of workers (Compute Engine VMs) and they all query the same datastore kind with status "open". They query with a limit of lets say 10k. The workers then update the status to "running" via put_multi (python).

Can read / write conflicts occur when entites are accessed at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud Datastore has some constraints about the usage, for example Datastore can handle a lot of operations but you need to follow the rule `500/50/5` as is mentioned in the Datastore's [best practices document](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/best-practices).

This rule said

> We recommend a maximum of 500 operations per second to a new kind, then increasing traffic by 50% every 5 minutes. In theory, you can grow to 740K operations per second after 90 minutes using this ramp up schedule. Be sure that writes are distributed relatively evenly throughout the key range.

Also best practices document mention:

> If you update an entity too rapidly, then your Datastore mode writes will have higher latency, timeouts, and other types of error. This is known as contention.

In my experience, the `contention` effect occurs when an entity is modified more than once in a second, my recommendation is to modify the same entity once per second (write operation)

By following these rules read and write at the same time would not be a problem in performance.

About data consistency, keep in mind that a read and write operations launched at same time will enter in a race condition and this might cause some unexpected results.

As is mentioned in the [transactions](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions#transaction_locks) document you can use these to delay a second transaction, avoiding the race condition due the transaction lock feature

In this [document](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/cloud-datastore-transactions#uses_for_transactions) are some code examples about data consistency by using transactions.

Comment: Just read up on race condition. I can see how that is a problem. So worker 1 might set an entity to "working" and worker 2 might read it as "open", since the write didn't occur yet. This entity would be proccessed twice. What if I use transactions for a single write and a single read?

Comment: @aydunno as is mentioned on the transactions documents you can use transactions to delay a second transaction, avoiding the race condition due the [transaction lock](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions#transaction_locks) feature

Comment: How do I use these locks? I've found nothing in the python API client docs

Comment: In this [document](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/cloud-datastore-transactions#uses_for_transactions) are some examples about data consistency